# Wpf and GPIO: is it possible?

Tags: wpf, iot, gpio

I have a WPF application which runs on a Windows 10 IOT device. The device has 4 inputs and 4 outputs and they should be read and written from a new release of the application.
All the sample code about GPIO I found are based on `using Windows.Devices.Gpio;`.

I made some tests with Visual Studio and I need a reference to Universal Windows  which is available only if I create a new project for UWP. It seems I cannot add GPIO functionality to an existing WPF project. What can I do? I would like to avoid porting the **WPF** project to **UWP**. A workaround valid only for the specific platform (x64) is acceptable.

Update 1

I added the references reported in the page suggested by Elgar and now I can compile using classes from Windows.Devices.Gpio namespace. Cannot access target hardware till next week so I cannot say if it works, but it is promising. In fact my development workstation doesn't have Gpio so I think it is correct if **GpioController.GetDefault()** returns null.

I found a [NuGet Gpio package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Device.Gpio) too. It refers to a completely different namespace, **System.Device.Gpio**, some classes look like the ones in **Windows.Devices.Gpio** but there are differences in the methods. I'm a bit disoriented because I cannot find any documentation on this package.

Comment: Check this link see if it helps. https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/

Comment: There's a net core nuget package. https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/10/dotnet-core-3-iot-raspberry-gpio/  If you target net core 3 in your wpf app then maybe you can add the package.

Comment: @Eldar I found useful information and I updated the initial question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

WPF on GPIO? It is not possible.

GPIO on UWP is an abstract layer that communicate on IOT's graphic subsystem devices, whereas WPF is on top of DirectX 9.0c. Those two are completely different in architecture and on the fundamental hardware abstraction layer. Therefore you can't mix UWP that runs on top of GPIO with WPF that runs on DirectX.